# Is it possible to refresh filters instead of reloading project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In my extension I add files and create filters for them in `project.vcxproj.filters` file (it's for C++ project). Now I'm doing something like this:

```
ProjectItems items;
items.AddFromFile(path);
// Mofify <project>.vcxproj.filters

project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll");
project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject");
project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject");
```

Is it possible just to update filters strcuture without reloading an entire project?